# Substring in urdu string

Tags: c#, asp.net, unicode, substring

How to apply substring on urdu string in asp.net? I have tried the substring method as descibed for english, but it doesnt work. Giving error

> Server Error in '/Ahp' Application. Redirect URI cannot contain
>   newline characters. Description: An unhandled exception occurred
>   during the execution of the current web request. Please review the
>   stack trace for more information about the error and where it
>   originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.ArgumentException: Redirect URI cannot
>   contain newline characters.
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 175:    private void showError(string msg) Line 176:    { Line
>   177:        Response.Redirect("Error.aspx?error=" + msg); Line 178:
>   } Line 179:
>
> Source File: c:\WorkSpace\Ahp\Default.aspx.cs    Line: 177
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [ArgumentException: Redirect URI cannot contain newline characters.]
>   System.Web.HttpResponse.Redirect(String url, Boolean endResponse,
>   Boolean permanent) +8892485    System.Web.HttpResponse.Redirect(String
>   url) +8    _Default.showError(String msg) in
>   c:\WorkSpace\Ahp\Default.aspx.cs:177    _Default.loadTopRatedNews() in
>   c:\WorkSpace\Ahp\Default.aspx.cs:170    _Default.Page_Load(Object
>   sender, EventArgs e) in c:\WorkSpace\Ahp\Default.aspx.cs:34
>   System.Web.Util.CalliHelper.EventArgFunctionCaller(IntPtr fp, Object
>   o, Object t, EventArgs e) +14
>   System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender,
>   EventArgs e) +35    System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +91
>   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +74
>   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean
>   includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +2207

I am redirecting error to error page with information of error

```
//--------------------- Its the code ------------------------------------
desc.Text = reader.GetValue(1).ToString().Substring(0,30);

//--------------- Main Error ---------------------------------------------------
Index and length must refer to a location within the string. Parameter name: length

//====================== Count checked of each ==================================
More then 540 character in each
```

Comment: The error indicates that part of the redirect URI is interpreted as having a new line character in it rather than a substring problem.  I would surmise that you are having an encoding problem of some kinds when building the URI for redirect.  For us to provide any meaningful help you need to post the relevant string and code that is causing the error.

Comment: From your box above: `Response.Redirect("Error.aspx?error=" + msg);` Maybe `msg` contains more than one line, i.e. contains cariage return plus newline characters? Are you sure this redirect is healthy?

Comment: desc.Text = reader.GetValue(1).ToString().Substring(0,30); Here gentleman what u require.

Comment: Instead of `Response.Redirect("Error.aspx?error=" + msg);` you should use `Response.Redirect("Error.aspx?error=" +  Server.UrlEncode(msg));` or similar. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zttxte6w.aspx.

Comment: Done, now updated the error.

Comment: I know you've added the `count checked for each` but can you confirm that that refers to the `reader.GetValue(1).ToString()` string?

Comment: Yes it is string. Contain urdu fonts. I can show u , i am printing them successfully but when i apply substring function then problem arise. I want to shorten my description which is written in urdu language. If there is any other method instead of sub string please tell me

Comment: There is almost nothing in your question that can be used to help you.  Please provide a minimal, self-contained program that demonstrates your problem.  It should contain an Urdu string and a Substring function call.

Comment: I already explained there is a urdu string and i want to take a substring... u can easily try ... it doesnt work both in c# and asp.net

Comment: I am willing to help, but I don't know anything about Urdu.  It's ok if you want to limit the pool of potential assistance to people who are already familiar with Urdu - that's your call.  The easier you make it for people to help you the more likely it is that you will receive help.

Comment: Thanks @bmm6o, I just want to restrict the string values in my form upto 200 characters, in english its quite easy. in urdu words are joint together. so i want to take a substring upto a word. But i didnt found any method which can work on unicode character substring. So i decided to make my own. :)